# why would textContent not trigger a reflow

Tags: css, innertext, reflow

I was looking at the difference between textContent and innerText on MDN.And it shows me something that confused me a lot.

1.innerText is aware of style and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas textContent will. (no problem, totally understand)

2.As innerText is aware of CSS styling, it will trigger a reflow, whereas textContent will not. (why?)

Comment: @Nit May be it's a bit foolish to ask like that.It seems that i have not made a fully understand of reflow yet.I found an article about it:
https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow
Now i got it.
Anyway, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Now i totally understand it! Since innerText only get visible texts, it should trigger reflow first(flush the queued reflow list) and re-calculating the style of the element.Then get the right result.

Comment: whereas textContent has not to do that.

Comment: You might want to specify here that the important part is that _reading_ the `innerText` causes the reflow, which really surprised me when I learned it the hard way. Now it is obvious even to me, because the engine has to take into account the CSS at the moment of accessing the value, and for this a reflow is triggered.

Answer (score 4):

I was suggested to answer this question instead of leaving comments. Though I did a lot more research after that. Now let's take a look at the differences again.

> innerText is aware of style and will not return the text of hidden
>   elements

Referenced from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

It means, innerText only get text from visible elements(not `display: none`, nor `visibility: hidden`). In addition, css styles applied on elements like `text-transform: uppercase` will also be taken into account. As a result, innerText will return the uppercased version of text while textContent will return the unchanged version. You can have a try of this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dyf19118/09f6zj9o/) on jsfiddle.

Since innerText needs to know what the most-recent style the element is, it should trigger reflow first (flush the queued reflow list) and re-calculating the style of the element.Then get the expected result.

Whereas textContent have not to do it since it's not aware of style.

If you are interested in more details of differences between innerText and textContent, you can have a read of this  [article](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/).