# More efficient/appropriate way to write this DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in Vanilla JavaScript and just made code to change HTML below.
It works but I'd like to know if there is a more efficient/appropriate way of doing this.
Thank you in advance for your help.

## HTML *BEFORE*

```
<section id="anchor-a">
<p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor-b">
<p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</section>
```

## HTML *AFTER*

```
<section>
<div id="anchor-a" class="anchor"></div>
<p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</section>
<section>
<div id="anchor-b" class="anchor"></div>
<p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</section>
```

## My JavaScript Code

```
const anchor = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="anchor-"]');
anchor.forEach((element) => {
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('anchor');
  newDiv.setAttribute('id', element.getAttribute("id"));
  ;
  element.insertBefore(newDiv, element.firstChild);
  element.removeAttribute('id');
});
```

Comment: I just modified them. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have a specific parent element inside which you need to search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more concise version would be to `insertAdjacentHTML`, which might be easier to read:

```js
const anchor = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="anchor-"]');
anchor.forEach((section) => {
  section.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div id="${section.id}">`);
  section.removeAttribute('id');
});
// next line is not needed, just cleans up the console output for demonstration
document.currentScript.remove();
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<section id="anchor-a">
<p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor-b">
<p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</section>
```

Also note that `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, and only newer browsers have a `NodeList.prototype.forEach` function. For older browsers and IE, either include a polyfill, or use `Array.prototype.forEach.call` instead:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[id^="anchor-"]'),
  (section) => {
    section.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div id="${section.id}">`);
    section.removeAttribute('id');
  }
);
// next line is not needed, just cleans up the console output for demonstration
document.currentScript.remove();
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<section id="anchor-a">
<p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</section>
<section id="anchor-b">
<p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</section>
```

(also, of course, if using ES6+ syntax, remember to transpile down to ES5 in addition to polyfills if you want to support *ancient* browsers)

Comment: Since you are using ES6 features, you can use `Array.from` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach.call`

Comment: I tried your code and it works great!
I'm using BABEL to transpile them but maybe it's not sufficient. I'll take note...
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'll search about "Array.prototype.forEach.call" as well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing this answer on performance, manipulating DOM in a loop is a bad idea. DOM interactions are the expensive operation, it is always advised to perform operation in loop.

What I would suggest is:

- Locate the parent element where search is to be performed.
- Make a clone of that.
- Perform your action on the elements. Since you are working on clone, you are not changing anything on DOM. Any operation done is in memory only.
- Now remove this container element and add processed clone to the parent element.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var copy = container.cloneNode(true);
const anchor = copy.querySelectorAll('[id^="anchor-"]');

anchor.forEach((element) => {
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('anchor');
  newDiv.setAttribute('id', element.getAttribute("id"));;
  element.insertBefore(newDiv, element.firstChild);
  element.removeAttribute('id');
});

container.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', copy)
container.remove();
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <section id="anchor-a">
    <p>lorem ipsum....</p>
  </section>
  <section id="anchor-b">
    <p>lorem ipsum....</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

**Note:** not changing any code relation to element processing as [CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s addresses that

#### Interesting read:

- [DOM interaction tips/dos and don'ts - Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45110434/3783478)